# Entity Framework linking an entity of its type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Basically, I'm creating an e-shop and I got stuck when creating categories. My code is as follows

```
public class Category
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string IdentifierName { get; set; }
        public Category Parent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Now what this is supposed to achieve is the ability to create subcategories even within subcategories. What it achieves instead is this error when building a migration:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Category' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Subcategories' set. To seed relationships you need to add the related entity seed to 'Category' and specify the foreign key values {'ParentID'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ParentId` to `Nullable` like this

```cs
public int? ParentID { get; set; }
```

and add `InverseProperty` on `Subcategory` to define relation between `Parent` and `Subcategories`

```cs
[ForeignKey("ParentID")]
public Category Parent { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Parent")]
public ICollection<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should have read the error. It was because of the way I seeded the data. To anyone who may stumble upon this, don't seed your equivalent of subcategories